# GSM modem problem

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, indicator, mobile-broadband, 3g

I have a problem with gsm (3g, LTE) modem. I use Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad x240. Since I started using this laptop gsm modem had been working great. Yesterday I've noticed that it's not working. There was no gsm signal power indicator only standard WiFi indicator. And I couldn't connect to internet. I restarted network-manager with:
sudo service network-manager restart
I got message that gsm (mobile) connection was established. But gsm indicator didn't show up, and still I couldn't connect to the Internet.
Restarting system helped. After restarting system I can connect using gsm modem but signal power indicator still is not present. There is only WiFI one. Unfortunately after closing laptop (system in sleep/suspend mode) modem stops working. To make it work I must restart Ubuntu.
I haven't installed any new software or made any changes in system and system settings recently. I think that gsm modem problems could have started after one of Ubuntu updates.

Update.

I've installed modem-manager-gui. I can send and receive sms messages without any problem. I still cannot connect to the internet after system sleep/suspend. Now internet works after network-manager restart. But still there is no gsm signal power indicator.

Update II

Now gsm modem works without any problem. But still there is WiFi power signal indicator instead of gsm one.